# Show a friendly error message when chat room tags exceed the maximum length

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, character-limit

We can add "tags" to chat room we own:

> [image]

That is a nice feature, however after some trial and error, I noticed that the length is limited. For example on MSE it appears to be 180 characters (including spaces).

All good, but when exceeding this limit and clicking "save", we get the dreaded "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" generic error page.

Can there be a friendly message please, either before or after submitting? (e.g. "this field can't exceed 180 characters" red banner to the right)

Comment: Probably a simple `maxlength` attribute on the text box would be sufficient.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen not sure, after some more trial and error, I suspect it's more complicated e.g. maybe the overall length of all the room meta data is limited, I was able to submit 200 characters for tags, in SO chat test room.

Comment: seems to be related to [this old question of mine...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260124/chat-room-info-description-max-length)

Comment: @SPArchaeologist yes indeed, very much related. Forgot about your report.